# How to serialize a Lookup<string, string> object into JSON?

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, serialization

I'm trying to serialize a Lookup into JSON by doing:

```
Lookup<string, string> productIdsByCategory = prodcuts.ToLookup(p => p.Category, p => p.Id);
```

Then in my ASP.NET Core WebAPI controller i'm returning by doing:

```
var response = new ComplexType
{
     PropertyA = productIdsByCategory
     ... other properties left out ...
};
return Json(response)
```

The response in Postman from my WebAPI look like this:

```
{
  "PropertyA": [
    [
      "ProductId_A"
    ],
    [
      "ProductId_B"
    ],
    [
      "ProductId_C"
    ]
  ],
  ... other properties left out ...
}
```

The keys are not included in the JSON response, is it even possible to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're right in that Newtonsoft.Json doesn't treat `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` nicely. The following code:

```
var input = new List<string>()
{
    "A1",
    "A2",
    "B1",
    "C1",
    "C2"
};

var lookup = input.ToLookup(i => i[0], i => i);
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lookup);

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Serializes as:

```
[["A1","A2"],["B1"],["C1","C2"]]
```

You correctly notice the key names (`A`, `B`, `C`) are missing, it appears to be serialized as an array of arrays.

There appears to be no support for serializing a lookup out of the box, so you'll have to write your own converter.

I found one [here](https://gist.github.com/TerribleDev/03bc02e064623fe634a1e70664ea225e), but that requires you to know the type of key and value on beforehand.

Modified it, this does the job:

```
        // Same as above, up till here
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lookup, new LookupSerializer());
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}

public class LookupSerializer : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        var result = objectType.GetInterfaces().Any(a => a.IsGenericType 
            && a.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ILookup<,>));
        return result;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var obj = new JObject();            
        var enumerable = (IEnumerable)value;

        foreach (object kvp in enumerable)
        {
            // TODO: caching
            var keyProp = kvp.GetType().GetProperty("Key");
            var keyValue = keyProp.GetValue(kvp, null);

            obj.Add(keyValue.ToString(), JArray.FromObject((IEnumerable)kvp));
        }

        obj.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "A": ["A1", "A2"],
    "B": ["B1"],
    "C": ["C1", "C2"]
}
```

Comment: Great answer. If anyone, like me, are using custom settings that you want to be used while serializing you can add the `serializer` parameter to the line where the IEnumerable is serialized; `obj.Add(keyValue.ToString(), JArray.FromObject((IEnumerable)kvp, **serializer**));`

Answer (score 11):

As a workaround to creating a custom converter, you could convert your `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` into a `Dictionary<TKey, List<TElement>>` which Newtonsoft.Json plays nice with.

```
myLookup.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
```

Comment: This is a very good workaround. Unfortunately it is not that efficient because of the hash code calculations involved by the Dictionary object.